# URL does not load in UIWebView but gets loaded into safari browser

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, uiwebview

I am loading one URL in UIWebView. It calls webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method but load an error page.

To load URL, I have used below code:

```
[customwebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]]];
```

Then I tried same URL in the Safari browser and it gets perfectly loaded.
This is the case only with iPhone4 with iOS 7.1.2.

I tried in simulator and device. Result is same.

Is there anything I need to set manually to load URL in UIWebView which is bydefault ON in Safari?

Comment: what is URL you are trying to load??

Comment: It is login page URL given by server in webservice response. It is getting loaded into device safari browser but not in WebView.

Comment: iAsh, Is there any special char in your URL?

Comment: It is HTML page URL and contains &,= etc. But does that affect on working of loading URL in browser that to only in WebView?

Comment: What happen with your problem? Do you resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

i was also not able to load urls like Facebook share dialog and twitter share.

But i got it fixed by encoding the url

use this :

```
NSString *encoded = [self.link stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encoded]];
self.webView.delegate = self;
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```